# Entity Framework 1 to 1 Relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a scenario where I optimally need a 1 to 1 relationship between two entities. I can do this with EF, but the end result is a model where I cannot insert any data as Entity Framework doesn't know which one to insert first. Same happens even if I change the relationship to be 0..1 to 0..1.

Let's take an example. I have an entity **File** and an entity **FileData**. File should always have a FileData and FileData should always have a File reference. I don't want these in the same entity(table) as FileData can get quite big and I mostly just need the stuff from the entity File.

I would like to specify a delete on cascade between the two so that if I delete a File, also a related FileData would get deleted.

I would also like to be able to insert them both in one transaction so I could write

```
new File { FileData = ...
```

So what would you prefer as a solution with Entity Framework? At the moment I've added a relation only to the File. This way I can submit both entities to the DB with one save, but I don't get delete on cascade as the primary record is FileData and it cascade works "wrong way" to my use case.

Comment: can you show your models code ?

Comment: Is generating model from database an option for you? If so, it would be easier to make the relevant tables in the database, add indexes with appropriate foreign keys, and finally with the click of a few buttons you can generate models automatically.

Comment: You can use this github project as a sample. Check out the File-FileData relationship. The current status of that relationship has some issues, but I would like it to be what I describe in here. https://github.com/antsim/EntityFrameworkTester

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To configure 1-1 relation ship, you have to configure it this way

```
// Configure FirstClassID as PK for SecondClass
    modelBuilder.Entity<SecondClass>()
        .HasKey(m => m.FirstClassId);

    // Configure FirstClassId as FK for SecondClass
    modelBuilder.Entity<FirstClass>()
                .HasRequired(m => m.SecondClass) 
                .WithRequiredPrincipal(m => m.FirstClass);
```

this will lead to `FirstClassId` is a primaryKey in both classes and a  foreign key in the second class, i.e , `SecondClass` is a weak entity

you might read more about one to one relation [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

hope this will help you